# RPN and Stack.pop() in C++

Tags: c++, stack

I am trying to implement a RPN calculator in C++. Following are the essential parts of the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool isNumberString(string &str);

int main()
{
    cout << "RPN Calculator Simulation" << endl;

    while (true)
    {
        string input;
        stack<double> operandStack;
        double lhs, rhs, result;

        cout << "> ";
        getline(cin, input);

        if (input == "Q" || input == "") {
            return 0;

        } else if (isNumberString(input)) {
            operandStack.push(atof(input.c_str()));

        } else if (input == "+") {
            rhs = operandStack.top();
            lhs = operandStack.top();

            result = lhs + rhs;
            operandStack.push(result);

        } else {
            cout << "Invalid command. Please try again." << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

bool isNumberString(string &str)
{
    if (str.length() == 0) return false;

    int numberOfDots = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == '.')
        {
            if (++numberOfDots > 1) return false;
        }
        else if (!isdigit(str[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Upon running and inputting two numbers, and entering '+' in the command line prompt, I get an error of "Expression: deque iterator not dereferencable."

Can anyone please offer advices on the problem with my codes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be getting a run-time error

As you're creating new stack every time in your `while` loop, there's nothing in `stack` when input `+` is given

`stack<double> operandStack;`

should be outside `while` loop

also the result is calculated on wrong inputs, you need to fix those modifying the logic a bit.

Comment: Yes, I will add stack::pop() to the operandStack stack for the calculation. Thanks for the reminder.